# Adding multiple items to a file

Tags: c#

I'm not sure what I need to put into this while loop (or if there's a better way to do it) in order to add all of the items in the itemsListBox to the file. Right now (without any while loop before the writer.writeline) it only adds the last item to the file. The program is supposed to add items to a list box and save them to a file, and then load them upon re-opening the program. It also has a label that keeps track of the number of items in the listbox.

```
private const string TO_DO_LIST = "to-do-list.txt";
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void enterButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AddItem();            
}

private void AddItem()
{
    itemsList.Items.Add(itemsBox.Text);
    numberOfItemsLabel.Text = itemsList.Items.Count.ToString();
    SaveItem();          
}

private void SaveItem()
{
    StreamWriter writer = File.CreateText(TO_DO_LIST);
    string newItem = itemsBox.Text;

    while ()//???
    {
        writer.WriteLine(newItem);
    }

    writer.Close();
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        StreamReader reader = File.OpenText(TO_DO_LIST);
        while (!reader.EndOfStream)
        {
            itemsList.Items.Add(reader.ReadLine());  
        }
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException ex)
    {             
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with just one line using `File.AppendAllLines`, which will open or create a file, append text to it, and close it.

The first argument is the file path, and the second argument is an `IEnumerable` of the lines you want to add.

Since `ListBox.Items` is a `ListBox.ObjectCollection`, we need to convert it to an `IEnumerable<string>` in order to use the `AppendAllLines` method. This can be done with the `Cast<string>()` method, combined with `ToList()`:

```
File.AppendAllLines(TO_DO_LIST, itemsList.Items.Cast<String>().ToList());
```

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this do the job?

```
using (StreamWriter writer = File.CreateText(TO_DO_LIST))
{
    foreach (string text in itemsList.Items)
    {
        writer.WriteLine(text);
    }
};
```

Comment: this somehow doesn't change anything, surely i'm missing something really simple